# How can I call the corresponding method given the generic type argument?

Tags: java, generics

I have a method having a generic type `T` as argument

```
private static <T> void doValidation(T[] pArray, int size, String firstName, String secondName) {

    ...

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        ...

        validate(pArray[i]);
    }
}
```

And then I have different method given the specific type, such as `A`, `B`, etc..

```
private static void validate(A a) {

}

private static void validate(B b) {

}
```

I would like it to resolve the type in runtime and call the corresponding method based on the type, is it possible?

At the moment I get

```
no suitable method found for validate(T)
    method ValidateDataStructure.validate(A) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; T cannot be converted to A)
    method ValidateDataStructure.validate(B) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; T cannot be converted to B)
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>doValidation(T[],int,String,String)
----
(Alt-Enter shows hints)
```

It wants me to cast of course the argument..

I am trying to do a port of Assimp, my intent is to be as much as possible close to the C structure. [This](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/master/code/ValidateDataStructure.cpp#L123-L145) is the function I am trying to port right now..

Comment: Its not possible. Generics is compile time only.

Comment: wow, that was fast :), so which alternative would you suggest?

Comment: You can't use polymorphism for static methods in Java. You could use instance methods and pass in instances that provide the `validate` method.

Comment: You can use switch or if-else

Comment: @SivaKumar, I can't `switch` based on the `T instanceof`, can I?

Comment: @elect, you can switch on `pArray[i] instanceof `

Comment: @elect yes ... You can use if-else with instanceof

Comment: @TagirValeev, it complains about `illegal start of type, incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to int` ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your exact needs, which aren't totally clear from your question, you have some options.

It seems like you probably don't actually need your `doValidation` method to behave differently depending on `T`, but rather your `validate` method to behave differently depending on the run-time type of its argument. This is a somewhat different problem, but it is easily solvable: the best option is probably to have it delegate to an overridable method, something like:

```
private static <T extends Validatable> void validate(T arg)
{
    arg.validate();
}
```

(You need to define an appropriate `Validatable` interface of course, and the `T` type parameter in the doValidation method also needs to be declared as `T extends Validatable`).

However, the above option requires that you can modify classes `A` and `B` (make them implement `Validatable`). Another option, not nearly as clean from a design point of view but without this limitation, is to determine the type and dispatch to a different method accordingly, by introducing a `validate` method with an `Object` argument as follows:

```
private static void validate(Object arg)
{
    if (arg instanceof A) {
        validate((A) arg);
    }
    else if (arg instanceof B) {
        validate((B) arg);
    }
    else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Don't know how to validate object of class " + arg.getClass.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I modified my question to specify my intent

Comment: Ok, I've got it (and you meant what I though you probably did). The "generic type argument" is pretty much a red-herring here. If the argument was of type `Object`, you'd still need to dispatch to the appropriate version of `validate`.

Comment: So what would you suggest me to go with?

Comment: I suppose you mean the first option, but given my purpose to have all the validation stuff in this file/class, I'd like to choose the second option

Answer (score 1):

If you want to validate types you cannot extend (e.g. `Integer`, `String`), 
you may implement your own dynamic dispatching. For example, you can create a map of validators like this (Java-8):

```
private static final Map<Class<?>, Consumer<?>> validators = new HashMap<>();

static {
    validators.put(A.class, (A a) -> validate(a));
    validators.put(B.class, (B b) -> validate(b));
    ...
}
```

And write a selector method:

```
static <A> Consumer<A> getValidator(Class<A> clazz) {
    // do nothing for unknown type
    return (Consumer<A>)validators.getOrDefault(clazz, () -> {});
}
```

Finally you can use it like this:

```
getValidator(value.getClass()).validate(value);
```

Comment: While the idea of having a map to determine the validator seems like a nice idea, it does have one drawback: it doesn't handle inheritance. I might have a perfectly good validator for class `B` and all its subclasses, but using this approach I have to create a map entry for each subclass. Of course that might not be an issue in practice.

Comment: I'd choose Davmac's answer, but thanks anyway for writing your answer, it is quite interesting, +1